# List available man page sections for an application

Tags: command-line, man

I am thinking about the man page sections *1 = user commands*, *2 = system calls* etc.

Is there a way, a command that will tell me what sections are available to read besides running something like `man 1 gedit`, `man 2 gedit`, `man 3 gedit` etc?

Comment: question was named a bit misleading. this is about sections across all manual pages listed in `man man` and not about an overview over all sections within a particular manpage. i will leave my answer in here anyway, which answers the latter question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731856/21880

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option:

```
apropos fork
```

to limit to exact word:

```
apropos -e fork
```

Alternatively, as *apropos* uses *regex* by default:

```
apropos "^fork$"
```

Alternatively use `man -k` instead of `apropos`.

Check out man pages for *apropos* and *man* for more details.

Comment: BTW, if you are using Cygwin, you may not find much output with `man -k`.

Comment: I don't understand it. If I use `man fork`, I see a man page for the syscall `fork` (manpage `FORK(2)`). If I use `apropos "^fork$"`, I get `nothing appropriate`. If I use `apropos fork`, I get a listing with commands like `pearlfork(1)`, `spfd(1)` and others, but not exaclty `fork`. By the way, I came to this answer trying to listman pages for `cc`, and I was having the same results (getting a man page for `man cc`, but not listing any man pages for exactly `cc` with `man -k cc`). Btw, I'm on Mac OS X, not sure if it is relevant.

Answer (score 18):

With the `man` from `man-db` at least:

```
$ man -f open
open (2)             - open and possibly create a file
open (1)             - start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).
open (3tcl)          - Open a file-based or command pipeline channel
open (3perl)         - perl pragma to set default PerlIO layers for input and output
```

Same as:

```
$ whatis open
open (2)             - open and possibly create a file
open (1)             - start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).
open (3tcl)          - Open a file-based or command pipeline channel
open (3perl)         - perl pragma to set default PerlIO layers for input and output
```

Or to get the paths of the man pages:

```
$ man -wa open
/usr/share/man/man1/openvt.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/open.3tcl.gz
/usr/share/man/man2/open.2.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/open.3perl.gz
```

To read all the man pages on a given topic, `man -a` is very common.

Note however that some implementations run one instance of the pager for each man page (you need to quit the pager to get to the next man page and there's no coming back), while some others pass the man pages as separate arguments to a single pager invocation (and you use `:n`, `:p` for instance with the `less` pager to navigate through the pages).

Comment: `man -wa open` was the only useful one in Mac OS X. How to open an specific man page, though? I mean, I know I can do `man 3 open`, but how to diferentiate between `/usr/share/man/man3/open.3tcl.gz` and `/usr/share/man/man3/open.3perl.gz` in your example? And why does it even make sense to have two entries for `man 3 open`?

Answer (score 3):

If you're `man` is from the "man-db" package, you can invoke this to see the "intro" page for each section of the manual:

```
man -a intro
```

If you know the location of the `man` pages database, this will list all of the section directories (man1, man2, man3, etc):

```
(cd /usr/share/man; ls -d man*)
```

Also if using `man` from the `man-db` package, you can see the location of the man pages database(s) by invoking `man -w` (this option also exists on FreeBSD `man`, but I don't have it installed so I don't know if it gives the same output).  For example, on Debian 8 (jessie):

```
$ man -w
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
```

Using `man -w`, a simple script to list all of the section numbers available in all of the man database directories would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=":$IFS"
for i in $(man -w)
do
    (
        cd "$i"
        for j in man*
        do
            if [ -d "$j" ]
            then
                echo "${j#man}"
            fi
        done
    )
done | sort -u
```

Comment: "If you're man is from the "man-db" package" -> how do I know wheter it is or not?

Answer (score 2):

I use my package manager to do this kind of stuff.

On Archlinux:

```
pacman -Ql gedit | grep /man/
```

RH/Fedora:

```
dnf repoquery -l gedit | grep /man/
```

Debian/Ubuntu/...

```
dpkg-query -L gedit | grep /man/
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command should list all available man page sections for a given command:

```
find /usr/share/man -name "<command>.*.gz" | egrep -o '[0-9]' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

to jump to a single section and open the manpage there:

```
m() 
{ 
    PAGER="cat" man "$1"|grep --color=auto ^\\w|sed '1d;$d'
    echo
    read -p"enter section here> " -r
    LESS="+/^${REPLY}" man "$1"
}
```

`m grep`

```
$ m grep
NAME
SYNOPSIS
DESCRIPTION
OPTIONS
REGULAR EXPRESSIONS
EXIT STATUS
ENVIRONMENT
NOTES
COPYRIGHT
BUGS
EXAMPLE
SEE ALSO

enter section here>
```

---

to have it a bit more interactively...
this will open a dialog(1) TUI you can navigate in: (only tested on ubuntu)

```
ms() {
        dpkg -s dialog &>/dev/null || { echo "Needs 'dialog' package which is not installed on this system!" && return; }
        [[ $# -lt 1 ]] && echo 'Man page name consisting of a single word expected but not given.' && return
        MANPAGE=$1
        [[ -n $2 ]] && DEFAULTCHOICE=$2 || DEFAULTCHOICE='0'
        man "${MANPAGE}" > /dev/null 2>&1 || { echo "${MANPAGE}" man page not present on this system!; return; }
        mapfile -t OUTLINE < <(PAGER="cat" man "${MANPAGE}" | grep ^\\w | grep -v -e AUTHORS -e COPYRIGHT | sed '1d;$d')
        RESULTSIZE="${#OUTLINE[*]}"
        # shellcheck disable=SC2046
        CHOICE=$(
                dialog --colors --keep-tite --default-item "$DEFAULTCHOICE" --menu "$(
                        echo -n \\Zb\\Z3 "${MANPAGE}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
                ) man page" $(( RESULTSIZE + 8 )) 55 "${RESULTSIZE}" $(
                        COUNT=0
                        for i in $( seq 0 $(( ${#OUTLINE[@]} - 1 )) )
                        do
                                echo -n "${COUNT}"
                                # shellcheck disable=SC2001
                                echo -n " $( echo "${OUTLINE[i]}" | sed 's/ /\_/g' ) "
                                (( COUNT++ ))
                        done
                ) 2>&1 >/dev/tty || echo CANCEL
        )
        [[ "$CHOICE" =~ "CANCEL" ]] && return
        # shellcheck disable=SC2001
        MANPAGER="less +/^$( echo "${OUTLINE[$CHOICE]}" | sed 's/ /\\ /g' )" man "${MANPAGE}"
        m "${MANPAGE}" "${CHOICE}"
}
```

`ms grep`